# how to solve the throw err, in the file system

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I am starting up node and want to write files but when i run the app i get the error
           fs.js:125
           throw err;
           ^

```
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'note.txt'
     at Object.openSync (fs.js:454:3)
     at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1247:35)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dawood Ibrar\Desktop\Node\notes- 
      app\app.js:3:4)
```

My Code is Under

```
      var fs = require('fs')

      fs.writeFileSync('note.txt','this notes was created by node')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.writeFileSync('./note.txt','this notes was created by node')
```